# Exchange MIME generation and TNEF

Tags: exchange, tnef

So normally when Exchange sends out a TNEF message, the message structure is something like this:

```
...

Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_000_AM0PR09MB277052D243401DC2ED6D32A4B27C0AM0PR09MB2770eurp_" 
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
 <AM0PR09MB277052D243401DC2ED6D32A4B27C0@AM0PR09MB2770.outlook.com> 

--_000_AM0PR09MB277052D243401DC2ED6D32A4B27C0AM0PR09MB2770eurp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable




--_000_AM0PR09MB277052D243401DC2ED6D32A4B27C0AM0PR09MB2770eurp_
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"


--_000_AM0PR09MB277052D243401DC2ED6D32A4B27C0AM0PR09MB2770eurp_--
```

A multipart mixed message with two mime parts: the plain text first, the TNEF part second. Rich text formatting and attachment are in the TNEF part. That's how we just to hate it.

#### Problem

Now I started seeing from two different domains a new MIME structure:

```
...

Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="_000_AM0PR06MB5394D1F1B085F52243304062FD4D0AM0PR06MB5394eurp_"

X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
 <AM0PR06MB5394D1F1B085F52243304062FD4D0@AM0PR06MB5394.outlook.com>


--_000_AM0PR06MB5394D1F1B085F52243304062FD4D0AM0PR06MB5394eurp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


[cid:image001.jpg@01D4D590.C0A2AB00]

--_000_AM0PR06MB5394D1F1B085F52243304062FD4D0AM0PR06MB5394eurp_
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"


--_000_AM0PR06MB5394D1F1B085F52243304062FD4D0AM0PR06MB5394eurp_
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Some.pdf"

--_000_AM0PR06MB5394D1F1B085F52243304062FD4D0AM0PR06MB5394eurp_
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image001.jpg"

--_000_AM0PR06MB5394D1F1B085F52243304062FD4D0AM0PR06MB5394eurp_--
```

Here the TNEF part seems to only include the rich formatting and the attachments are part of the mixed multipart. Unfortunately with this mime generation, the `Content-ID` is not preserved, so the cid reference in the text part and in the HTML encode in TNEF part can't be resolved.

#### Question

My question is **NOT** how to disable TNEF in general. My question is what configuration triggers this short of MIME generation.

Some more headers that might give a clue:

```
x-originating-ip: ...
x-ms-publictraffictype: Email
x-ms-office365-filtering-correlation-id: ...
x-microsoft-antispam: ...
x-ms-traffictypediagnostic: ...
x-ms-exchange-purlcount: 1
x-microsoft-exchange-diagnostics: ...
x-microsoft-antispam-prvs: ...
x-forefront-prvs: 0970508454
x-forefront-antispam-report: ...
received-spf: ...
x-ms-exchange-senderadcheck: 1
x-microsoft-antispam-message-info: ...
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-OriginatorOrg: kairos.be
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-Network-Message-Id: 2530d08a-1094-4f6f-fa0d-08d6a39f8227
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-originalarrivaltime: 08 Mar 2019 08:24:39.6698
 (UTC)
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-fromentityheader: Hosted
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-id: ...
X-MS-Exchange-CrossTenant-mailboxtype: HOSTED
X-MS-Exchange-Transport-CrossTenantHeadersStamped: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

And according [this KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/290809/how-e-mail-message-formats-affect-internet-e-mail-messages-in-outlook), TNEF can exist in a MIME-encoded message as a MIME body part of type "application/ms-tnef,". It maybe because the sender uses RTF instead of HTML as their email format.